# How can I use Protractor to search through a class, find a p tag in the class and verify some of its text?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, jasmine, protractor

What I am trying to do is to find a way to use Protractor to locate a class and search through all of the p tags in that class to see if any of them contain "Glennville, GA" in the text.

This is what I've been trying to do in my spec file:

```
it('should filter results by location', function() {
    browser.driver.wait(function(){
        return browser.driver.isElementPresent(by.id('jobLocationFilter'));
    });
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('jobLocationFilter')).click();
    browser.driver.findElement(by.css('[value="5"]')).click();
    browser.driver.wait(function() {
        return browser.driver.isElementPresent(by.css('[class="Title"]'));
    });
});
```

Essentially, what I've done is selected an option from a drop down menu and I need to write an expect that verifies I've selected that option. I've tried a different number of ways of doing that, but I can't seem to find one that works for me.

This is the HTML that I'm working with:

```
<div class="jobEntry">
   <span class="Title">
      <a href="/rewrite_your_future/job_postings/122">Lead QA Test Engineer</a>
   </span>
   <p>Lead QA Engineer Glennville, GA</p>
</div>
```

How to write the code to do what I need it to do? I haven't been able to figure it out.

Oh, and this is my .conf file in case that helps:

```
exports.config = {
framework: 'jasmine',
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
specs: ['spec.js']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`element.all()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder) + [`filter()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) and eventually check the [`count()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.count):

```
var desiredElements = element.all(by.css("div.entry p")).filter(function (elm) {
    return elm.getText().then(function (text) {
        return text.indexOf("Glennville, GA") >= 0;
    });
});
expect(desiredElements.count()).toBeGreaterThan(0);
```

Comment: I tried that out and received an error I haven't seen before. Failed: Class constructors cannot be invoked without 'new'. Do you know what this means?

Comment: @AP1 well, I'm sure this is not related to the code I've proposed. How are you trying to apply the suggested solution?

Comment: hmmm I haven't received this error yet, any idea what it means? I tried doing a quick google search and haven't found too much yet. I use skype a lot to message people about coding and stuff. You can add me at AnthonyClassUse if you want. I'm always trying to learn something and you have a lot of experience and maybe not mind sharing every once in awhile if I have a question.

Comment: I figured out the reason. It was  because of a bug with the latest version of Protractor. When I uninstalled it a installed an earlier version of Protractor, this worked for me! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if jobEntry class is unique and you only have one p tag inside, the below should do it:

expect(element(by.css('[class="jobEntry"]'))
   .element(by.tagName('p')).getText()).toContain('Glennville, GA');